# [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified [Dynamics GP]

Tags: odbc, connection-string, adodb, dexterity, dynamics-gp

I'm trying to create a form upload transaction from excel to table via dexterity tools then copy some code from samples scripts. The steps i got from [references](https://www.dofactory.com/reference/connection-strings)
similarly on these scripts:

```
conn.ConnectionString = 
   "Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};" + 
   "Driverid=790;" + 
   "Dbq=C:\MyPath\SpreadSheet.xls;" + 
   "DefaultDir=C:\MyPath;"; 
conn.Open();
```

another sample from my superior which script looks like these:

```
sheetbuf = itemname('(L) Sheet' of window PMS_Upload_Budget, '(L) Sheet' of window PMS_Upload_Budget);
buf1 = sheetbuf;
sheetbuf = "[" + sheetbuf +"$]";
recordset = COM_CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset");

sDriverExcel="{Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)}";
sConString="DRIVER="+sDriverExcel+";DriverId=790;DBQ="+'(L) Native Path'+";DefaultDir=";

recordset.Open("SELECT COUNT(*) as RowCount FROM " + sheetbuf, sConString);
row = recordset.Fields.Item[0].Value;

recordset.Close();
recordset.Open("SELECT * FROM " + sheetbuf, sConString);
col = recordset.Fields.Count[];
```

When i tried to sample both of those scripts, gain error like these
[image: warning]

Then, i ask for another assistance from my other superior. He give me these script:
[image: sample2]

So, i tried to follow his assistance by installing `AccessDatabaseEngine_X64.exe`
and changing the connection string with these script:

```
sConString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" 
+ '(L) FullPath' + ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml; HDR=YES;IMEX=1"";";
```

Then again, got these error:
[image: Provider cannot be found]

Recently, i look the connection string on excel power query and tried to transfer data inside a table to other workbook. Then, this window comes up to ask my [image: credentials]. So, i assume ODBC without DSN from my first [references](https://www.dofactory.com/reference/connection-strings) not working properly. Then, i tried to add these script to power query:

```
conn.ConnectionString = 
          "Dsn=DsnName;" + 
          "Uid=UserName;" + 
          "Pwd=Secret;";
```

But, the window shows a warning says "The Connection property 'uid' can only be provided using credentials. So, i stuck finding alternative way to input pwd parameter into power query nor dexterity script.

Latest thing i ever tried is looking at OLE/COM object viewer(hundreds objects) and process monitor(millions event). Any tips regarding similar issues could be useful here, thanks.

Comment: Are you still having an issue here? Something isn't adding up. You're specifying the extended property as XML, but your Excel file is XLS (or is it?). So that's one obvious problem. I've never needed to pass a user ID or password to an Excel connection, so that seems to be another issue. None of the examples on the site you linked show a uid/pwd being passed to an Excel connection either. Your first string has a bunch of unnecessary properties too.

Comment: Try something simple like this: `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\MyPath\SpreadSheet.xls;
Extended Properties="Excel 8.0;HDR=YES";` assuming it's actually an .XLS file.

Comment: i tried it with other quote options and still having the [Provider error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbRlL.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fix my previous script into this from my friend references

```
sheetbuf = itemname('(L) ExcelRow' of window Integrate_Transaction, '(L) ExcelRow' of window Integrate_Transaction);
buf1 = sheetbuf;
sheetbuf = "[" + sheetbuf +"$]";
connection = COM_CreateObject("ADODB.Connection");
recordset = COM_CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset");

conString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + '(L) FullPath' + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
connection.Open(conString);
recordset.Open("SELECT COUNT(*) as RowCount FROM " + sheetbuf , connection, ADODB.adOpenDynamic, ADODB.adLockOptimistic);
row = recordset.Fields.Item[0].Value;

recordset.Close();
```

So, i suspected the dexterity library should install something else for those two other constring. Thanks for trying to answer my confusion tho, i'd appreciate more answers for those two constring ^^